# Hover Effect (CSS)

Tags: css, hover

I would like to add hover effect for navigation link.
Effect: a small width line lift up when hover.
I found a website is using this hover effect, pls look at the top navigation.
www.ambientlounge.sg

Any idea on how to do it?

Thanks in advance.
Andy

Comment: may i know wat docs u referring to?

Comment: Any docs. MDN for example.

Answer (score 0):

Just check out the [W3Schools page](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp) on the CSS :hover tag.

Your CSS file would look something like:

```
.element:hover{
  border-bottom: 3px solid grey;
}
```

That would give you the underlining without the smooth fall in.  If you're looking to do something similar to what the website has, then use JQuery.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I am looking the smooth fall in actually, what should I search for JQuery? Do you have the effect name?

Comment: Probably the [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function.  You'll need to know a bit of Javascript or at least brush up on it.  It's not a pure CSS solution though, like you were looking for.